# Versioning Liferay's JournalTemplate

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

**Question:** Is there any way to adopt versioning for Liferay's webcontent templates , like it is available for the webcontent articles?

I find that there is a field **"version"** in **"JournalArticle"** table , but not in **"JournalTemplate"**.

**Scenario/Requirement:** 
We have developed our pages containing a set of journal articles. The code for the journal template resides in its editor itself. (Unlike coming from a versioned theme plugin using #parse()).

I understand , that placing the code in the template's editor is not a very good idea, but our clients want it that way , so that their content editors don’t have to wait for a code roll-out to carry out their changes.

So whenever a change is made to the template , we want it to be versioned, so that we can revert back to any of the earlier versions , when needed.

We are using Liferay version 6.0.6 CE.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Liferay itself is not supporting in any way versioning of templates, neither structures (at least so far in 6.2 and all lower versions, including your) The official recommendation we get from their support was to keep versions itself by creating new version of template with version suffix like **BANNER-1.1**

Let me know if this is idea which you can adopt to your scenario.